# SQL how to keep synonyms/alternative words

Tags: sql, ruby

I am wondering how to keep synonyms in database. For example:

1. Word school have synonyms like: college, academy
2. If I put in form 'school' response should contain [college, academy] 
   otherwise If I write college I want to get [school, academy]

I thought about one table with one column where I will have

```
college,academy,school,
```

Then I'd query the table with

```
SELECT * FROM synonyms WHERE word LIKE 'school'
```

Is It good solution of this problem? Maybe better way is to use two tables? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use one table `words` with many-to-many connection called synonyms. So in fact it would be two tables, `words` with `id:integer, word:string` and a second one `synonyms_words`: `word_id:integer, synonym_id:integer`. Then your sql query would be:

```
SELECT synonyms.word 
  FROM words 
    INNER JOIN synonyms_words 
      ON synonym_words.words_id = words.id
    INNER JOIN words AS synonyms
      ON synonyms_words.synonyms_id = synonyms.id
  WHERE words.word = 'school'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is okay but not good. Yes, you can see a group of synonyms as an entity and store them thus. (You would start and end each group with delimiters though, i.e. ',college,academy,school,' to be able to ask WHERE words like '%,school,%'.) However looking up a word would always result in a full table scan, which is not efficient.

Moreover, to show the synonyms for 'school' you would want to display 'college, academy' rather than ',college,academy,school,'. And maybe one would want to look up additional synonyms for 'academy' then. So you are suddenly dealing with single words instead of dealing only with the synonym group. So to store the words as concatenated strings is no longer advisable.

What you need is a table of words. And you need synonym groups.

You can do this with two tables, one with words and one for the synonym groups:

```
Table words:

id | word
---+----------------
1  | college
2  | school
3  | academy
4  | group of fish

Table groups:

id | id_word
---+----------------
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 3
2  | 2
2  | 4
```

Or do it with a single table:

```
Table groups:

group_id | word
---------+----------------+
1        | college
1        | school
1        | academy
2        | school
2        | group of fish
```

Both approaches have their advantages as to ease of access, maintenance, storage etc.